# Having trouble with an undeclared identified, even though i included my .h file(C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a stack using a linked list, my Node struct is the private data of my ListStack class. When i try and use Node in my main.cpp it says that Node is an undeclared identifier. By the way i'm using this stack and everything to implement a RPN calculator and i have 3 files calculator.h, calculator.cpp, and main.cpp(if that is relevant)

Here is the struct:

```
struct Node
{
    double data;
    Node* under;
};

Node* top;
```

I have included the .h file(calculator.h) with `#include "calculator.h"`

The first statement it doesn't recognize is `Node* current= top;` it also does not recognize top. Any reason for this? I'm kind of new to this site so sorry if I haven't included enough information.

Comment: What is `top` in your code?

Comment: @another.anon.coward it's of type `Node*`

Comment: Sorry my bad! Missed the declaration part before indentation.

Comment: Is Node declared in the same file as the class declaration?

Comment: Yes it is declared there

Comment: Show us more code, such as how you are using `Node* current= top`.  Also realize that all variables declared in header files will be declared in each source file that includes the header, resulting in duplicate copies of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your structure is a private variable of a class you can't call it like that, you need something like

```
MyClass::Node mynode;
```

Comment: I did that and it cleared the undeclared problem, but now it is telling me that my data is private. Should i just make my struct public? Or is it possible to declare main.cpp as a friend?

Comment: You don't declare a file as a friend, you can declare a class as a friend of another so the friend class can access the other class' private members. You need to make it public or, conversely, you may need to take the structure out of that class. All fields are public in a structure.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, i've figured it out, is there a way to mark this as answered? or do i just delete it?

Comment: To mark it as answered by me just click the "V" sign on the left of my answer. To answer it yourself click "Add another answer" and accept it in two days